# Is the reverse statement to "open" in Munkres topology true?

Tags: general-topology, definition

There is a problem:

> Given $(X, \tau), A \subseteq X, \forall x \in A, \exists U \in \tau,
>  x \in U \text{ s.t. } U \subset A \implies A$ is open in $X$

So what I did was to show that $A$ is in $\tau$ by taking union of all $\bigcup_{x \in A} U_x$.

Is it true the oppose way?

> $A$ is open $\implies A \subseteq X, \forall x \in A, \exists U \in
>  \tau,  x \in U \text{ s.t. } U \subset A $

Original problem attached:
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "open"?

Comment: @Jack The only one given is that it belong to the topology on some set $X$

Comment: Do you mean for $U\subset A$ to be a strict inclusion?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Again, an answer would depend on what definition you use for "open".

Comment: @Jack The definition I was given is: A set is open if it is an element in the topology $\tau$

Comment: It is true if the inclusion is not strict.

Comment: @Jack I don't understand your confusion. "Open" means in the topology.

Comment: Wait wait wait, this is question 1 in Ch2 of Munkres' book on topology. Surely I am not the only one who has encountered this :-)

Comment: Well if U can equal A it's trivially true.  If U must be proper subsets it needn't be true at all, for example A could be only open set.  For metric spaces this is the definition of open and mu s the true.

Comment: Fair enough. I was thinking about open set in a metric space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you've written this, with a strict inclusion $U\subset A$, this is not necessarily true.  For instance, suppose $X=\{x\}$ has only one point (with $\tau$ the unique topology on $X$) and $A=X$.  Then $A$ is open and $x\in A$, but there is no open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and $U\subset A$, since the only proper subset of $A$ is the empty set!

However, if you write a nonstrict inclusion $U\subseteq A$ instead, then this is true.  If $A$ is open, then for any $x\in A$, you can just take $U=A$, and then $U\in\tau$ and $x\in U\subseteq A$.

Comment: I think it is a notation issue with Munkres' second edition (or maybe all his editions). I have flipped through the pages but I could not find even a single instance where $\subseteq$ was used.

Comment: Yes, quite a few authors use $\subset$ to mean nonstrict subset (which personally I think is just terrible).

Comment: Munkres explicitly says in the text that $\subset$ does not indicate strict inclusion, and instead has special notation for strict inclusion. He does not use $\subseteq$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thanks I was trying to find where he might have made this clarification

Comment: My first rigorous math course used Munkres and I used $\subset$ his way until someone who attended my talk at a combinatorics conference pointed out that combinatorics is not topology and I should use $\subseteq$.

Comment: If it's not strict inclusion then it's trivial.  For each $x\in A $ there exists an open $U =A $ so that $x\in U \sebset A $.

Comment: @MattSamuel, you could have told them that you are not doing high school math.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that $\subset$ does not mean "strict inclusion", which is usually denoted as $\subsetneq$. Since you mentioned Munkres, here is an excerpt from his *Topology*:

[image]

For your question, it is true. Suppose $A$ is open, namely, $A\in\tau$. For any $x\in A$, let $U=A$. Then $U\in\tau$ and $U\subset A$.